# HTTP Basic Authentication combined with SSL/TLS (HTTPS) will be used to authenticate user

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, curl, iis-7

i need to send json request (RESTful) to a URL where the server authority send me the username & password and ask me to send the request to the server using **"HTTP Basic Authentication combined with SSL/TLS (HTTPS) will be used to authenticate user"**.

when i send the request to that link using cURL then i get the error.
"**Error: call to URL failed with status 0, curl_error SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate, curl_errno 60**"

My Web server version is: IIS7, PHP Version: 5.3.27.

Now, what is the process to complete the task. please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with HTTP Basic Auth but with certificate You've generated for Your server, which is not signed.

If it's You dev server You can switch off SSL verification

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

In case it's production You have to sign Your certificate with proper CA.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but it's not working. could you please give me any suggestion that "How can i generate signed certificate in iis7 using their provided username & password"?

Comment: You've generated certificate, but it's self-signed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

You can buy signed certificate using for example this website: https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo.aspx